# How can I use the local state, but get the initial value of this state from the props?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, storybook

I have this component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import IconSvg from 'ui/Icon/IconSvg'
import IconSwitchOn from 'ui/Icon/controls/switch-on'
import IconSwitchOff from 'ui/Icon/controls/switch-off'

interface SwitchProps {
  checked: boolean
  onChange?: () => void
}
export const Switch: React.FC<SwitchProps> = ({ checked, onChange }) => {
  const [check, setCheck] = useState<boolean>(checked)
  console.log('checked=', checked, ', check=', check) // check = false always

  const onChangeLocal = () => {
    setCheck(prev => !prev)
    if (onChange) {
      onChange()
    }
  }
  return (
    <button type="button" role="switch" onClick={onChangeLocal}>
      {check ? <IconSvg Svg={IconSwitchOn} /> : <IconSvg Svg={IconSwitchOff} />}
    </button>
  )
}
```

It shows either the icon "On" or the icon "Off" when clicked, the icons change. The initial value comes through the props "checked"

Initially, it did not use the useState at all and everything worked fine there. But then I got the task to put this component in the Storybook. And for this it needs to have his own state. So that in the storybook the icons change when clicked, but the component does not know anything about Redux.

The modified component works, but the original value "check" is always equal to "false". I understand that this is because the useState is asynchronous, but then what to do?

How can I use the local state, but get the initial value of this state from the props?

Comment: Components in storybook don't need their own state, you can define state in the story file

Comment: In a storybook, you can have a state and not have a state. In any case, the question remains: how to assign the initial state from the prop to useState?

Comment: Decision:
  useEffect(() => {
    setCheck(checked)
  }, [checked])